# XML serialization with c# & windows forms

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to create a waypoint generator using windows forms, that allows a user to create waypoint & path data via a GUI & output the data to an XML file. I've chosen to take advantage of the built in c# XML serialization feature, but have been unable to format the XML output in the way required by the client.

A stripped version of the waypoint data object would look something like the following:

```
// Waypoint data class
[XmlRoot("RootNode")]
public class WaypointProjectData
{
    [XmlElement("Map")]            // Also tried to use XmlElementAttribute,
    [XmlAttribute("file")]         // XmlAttributeAttribute, and many variations
                                   // of these qualifiers, with no success
    public string       m_szMapImageFileName;

    [XmlAttribute("width")]
    public int          m_iWidth;

    [XmlAttribute("height")]
    public int          m_iHeight;

    [XmlArray("Nodes")]
    public ArrayList    m_aoNodes;

    WaypointProjectData()
    {
        m_szMapImageFileName = "map.png";
        m_aoNodes = new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

The client requires that the XML output conforms with the following layout/format:

```
<RootNode>
  <Map file="map.png" width="100" height="100" />
  <OtherData var="variable" data="10" />
  <Nodes>
    <Node x="10" y="30" />
    <Node x="30" y="20" />   // etc...
  </Nodes>
</RootNode>
```

Some clear examples on how to do this using c# xml serialization would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You can use an XmlElement or XmlAttribute node but not both on a given property.  Perhaps create one object per XmlNode that you need, map to attributes of that element, and merge the XML results yourself?

Comment: When commenting out [XmlElement("Map")], the file string, width & height data are all added as attributes of the root node. Alternatively, when commenting out [XmlAttribute("file")], the file string is placed within element tags after the root node, however the width & height are still placed as attributes of the root node.

Comment: Yes Eric, you're correct. I probably should have pointed out that I left them both in the code above merely to indicate that I had tried them both, not that they are intended to work together. Also, the nodes are each created as objects that are added to the arraylist through functions within the above object, which I did not include in the above code. While I will eventually want to serialize the nodes as well, the main problem I'm experiencing is that I'm not sure how to serialize the above data as custom-named attributes within custom-named elements.

Answer (score 1):

When I have to serialize something in a specific Xml format like this, I start with a schema (inferred if necessary, hand-crafted if known). Then I use the VS xsd tool to create the serialization classes (and yes, I know xsd can be used for the inferring schema part—I just never bother with it for that purpose).

So if you have an xsd file like this one created from your example (note that I specified data types as much as possible—this helps the xsd tool to use the appropriate types for properties):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="RootNode">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Map">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="file" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:decimal"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="height" type="xs:decimal"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="OtherData">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="var" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="data" type="xs:decimal"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Nodes" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Node" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:decimal"/>
                                    <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:decimal"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If you name this Root.xsd, then you can go to the VS command line and run

xsd Root.xsd /c /n:myProject.Xml

That'll create a class file (named Root.cs because that's the default when processing Root.xsd) that contains objects you can easily plug into .Net to serialize and deserialize the XML. Note that I specified the namespace the classes will have ("/n:myProject.Xml"). I prefer to control that namespace, but defaults are usually fine for the rest. Further, the tool creates partial classes, so if you want custom property accessors, you're fine to add them in a separate file that won't get creamed if you need to run the tool again.

Another tip, I create a text file in my project with the name "<xsd name> xsd Command Line.txt". That way I just have to paste that into the VS command line and don't have to remember everything else I used.

Comment: I appreciate the effort it took to make this response, however it really doesn't answer my question. There is a specific layout which must be followed for the file output from the waypoint generator to be compatible with the client's software. Not only does the above example depart considerably from that format, it also lacks what I asked for: an example of the c# implementation used to create the output. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Copy that schema into an xsd and run the VS xsd tool and you'll have exactly what you're looking for: i.e. an example of the c# implementation used to create the output. I thought that was pretty clear. I didn't include the actual auto-generated code because I figured you'd want to tweak it on your own to achieve the results you truly desire. After all, nobody *really* wants a node called "OtherData" with attributes of "var" and "data"...

Comment: Oh, oops. I misunderstood your post to mean that I have my generator output in one (schema) format, and then convert that file to the desired format via another (part of the) program, which seemed like a roundabout way of getting to the end result. Thanks for the clarification.
I'll have a poke around the VS xsd/schema tool and see what I can come up with.

Comment: It's an *extremely* useful tool when you have to deal with Xml serialization.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you go off the beaten track serialisation is a huge PIA.
You need something to mark up as map, probably OtherData as well, so that means you need a class or struct that corresponds to the node.
e.g. WaypointProejctdata as a class Map, that has properties filename, width and height.
My general rule of thumb, is as soon as I have to start messing with my objects to get the xml, serialisation gets binned,and I add an interface that takes an XmlReader or Writer and implement it.
Tryng to get serialisation to do what you want is usually way more code and far less comprehensible than doing that.